# Lock database for other application

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, encryption, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, someone is using my database via a macro code in Excel, is there any way to prevent another application (like Excel) to access my database?

Comment: Are they supposed to be able to use it?

Comment: Please clarify: do you only want one instance of any application to access it at a time?  You cannot prevent other applications from accessing the database if they are written to do so, but you can put the database in single user mode.

Comment: my sql is on a server and I only want that my apps access it.

Comment: SQL Server access is controled by login/user authentication, use a specific user/login for your applicatoin and give that login access to your server, revoke permissions to all other users/logins.

Comment: I have already declared a user but someone is accessing it via the "sa" user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your users are supposed to acces the database (they have login and rights on it) but only with a limited range of software, you have to tell them not to use Excel.
There is a workaround based on an after connect trigger wich check the application_name in session, but its not very effective.

If they do not have to connect directly to the database, you have to delete their logins (or revoke rights) or change password if they shared a common user.

Answer (score -1):

Create a service (e.g.in C#.NET) which will be used to query the database. In programming language like C# you can easily lock the database via "lock" statement.

Comment: Question hasn't got enough detail for you to provide this as a solution.